# Create string[] from string with ampersand

Tags: c#

I want to convert string to string array using "," separator. I'm using this code below but when string has an ampersand cuts the end of string.

```
string example = "one,two,three&four";
return new []{ example };
```

// result `["one,two,three"]`

How can I get the result: `["one","two","three&four"]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Split` not `Join`.

Please try to this:

```
string[] result = example.Split(',');
```